# How to search entire XML column for a string in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I want to create a query that searches a string in the entire XML column.

My table name is `msg`. it has two fields `ID` and `xmlmsg`
`ID` is of type INT and `xmlmsg` is of type XML.

I want to write a query to search for '123456' in `xmlmsg` column and return the ID.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. I have used Xquery to do this. There are several sites that helps in learning Xquery and find one such site here for practice [ClickMe](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10279/xquery-labs-a-collection-of-xquery-sample-scripts.aspx)

```
DECLARE @msg TABLE 
        (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), XMLmsg XML)

INSERT INTO @msg
  (
    XMLmsg
  )

SELECT  '<Root>
<MsgDescription MsgID="123456">
</MsgDescription>
</Root>'
UNION ALL
SELECT  '<Root>
<MsgDescription MsgID="123457">
</MsgDescription>
</Root>'
UNION ALL
SELECT  '<Root>
<MsgDescription MsgID="123458">
</MsgDescription>
</Root>'


SELECT   *
FROM     @msg
WHERE    XMLmsg.exist('(/Root/MsgDescription[@MsgID=''123456''])') = 1

GO
```